# GROUP_CONCAT with WHERE IN clause

Tags: mysql, group-concat

I am trying to group multiple columns together that have certain matching strings.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`users`.`id`) 
FROM `users` 
WHERE `users`.`name`
IN ('john','doe','foo','bar');
```

I'm not getting an error, just the result is `NULL`, even though there are columns with all those names in the table.

How do I structure my query to accomplish the expected outcome?

Comment: It looks fine to me. What is the complete error message?

Comment: My apologies, there was no error. Just the result in the table is NULL, but there are columns with all those `name`s in the table.

Comment: Works here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/57420/1

Comment: If you're getting `NULL` then none of the `name` columns match the `IN` clause. Post some example table contents.

Comment: What do you get if you use `SELECT users.id` without `GROUP_CONCAT`?

Comment: one way to deal with nulls in concat situations is to use coalesce, for example `select group_concat(coalesce(users.id, '--no-id--'))` this way the concat function doesnt fail

Comment: @santiagoarizti Not necessary, `GROUP_CONCAT` ignores nulls.

Comment: And if `id` is the primary key, as is likely, it can't be `NULL`.

Comment: NULL is expected value if there are no rows in the table, or if there are no rows that satisfy the condition in the WHERE clause, or if there are rows, the value if `id` column from all of those rows is NULL. Step 1 in debugging this, as @Barmar already indicated, is to remove the `GROUP_CONCAT`, and verify that the query is not returning any rows. Step 2 is to figure out what values of `name` are actually in the table... remove the `WHERE` clause, and include the `name` column in the SELECT list.

Comment: I advise developing SQL by stepwise refinement. Start with a query that "works".  `SELECT u.id, u.name FROM users u`.  Verify that is returning what we expect. Then make a small change... for example, add a WHERE clause.   `WHERE u.name IS NOT NULL`. Add to/modify the query step by step until you get something that doesn't work, then backup a step to what was working. (There's no evidence in this question of *any* working query that is returning expected results.)

Comment: @spencer7593 I agree, @Barmar after a left join you might get nulls in a primary key from the secondary table, but yes, my recommendation applies to simple `concat()` perhaps not to `group_concat()` but it will help to put something in the coalesce to see where a value was supposed to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q: How do I structure my query to accomplish the expected outcome?

A: Backup to the previous query, the one that was working, and returning expected results. And then figure out why the change you made to that query caused the unintended behavior/unexpected results.

For example, likely you started writing the query like this:

```
SELECT u.id
     , u.name 
  FROM users u
 ORDER
    BY u.name
```

And you ran that to test it, and verify that it returned expected results. Is `id` non-NULL. Is `name` column populated?

Next, you added `WHERE` clause, to see if you could get rows that had a `name` column containing 'john'.

```
SELECT u.id
     , u.name 
  FROM users u
 WHERE u.name = 'john'
 ORDER
    BY u.name
```

Did that return expected results when you ran that? If not, we need to figure out why not. What's different about that query than the one that was working.

How far did we get with this stepwise refinement, in writing the query, before we got to a query that is returning unexpected results? Show us that.

And then explain why a change made to that query, into a different query, should produce a particular result.  i.e. what results are the "expected outcome". And Why is that outcome expected?

---

Absent a specification, it's impossible to make any recommendations. Sample data and example output would go a long ways towards clarifying the requirements. You might even go so far as setting up a SQLFiddle example.

If you are asking a busy colleague for help, it behooves you to show some work, how far you got. Rather than just "here's a query that doesn't work".

https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

---

Otherwise, we're just guessing at what result you are expecting to be returned.

Maybe the answer is as simple as wrapping an expression in an `IFNULL`

```
SELECT IFNULL( GROUP_CONCAT(foo) ,'')  AS bar
     ,
```

But we are likely barking guesses up the entirely wrong tree.